# Swagger model for key with array values

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I am stuck with creating a model with key and array of values. But I am unable to get my expected result. Guide me how to achieve the expected result

**model.json**

```
"models":{  
      "SearchTask":{  
         "id":"SearchTask",
         "properties":{  
            "taskStatusList":{  
               "type": "array",
                "items": {
               "type": "string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
        "taskStatusList": ["String"]

}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
 {
            "taskStatusList": ["a","b"]

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For the array inner type, you can use the `example` construct to give a single example for the value:

```
{
  "models": {
    "SearchTask": {
      "id": "SearchTask",
      "properties": {
        "taskStatusList": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {
            "type": "string",
            "example": "a"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You cannot have multiple examples with the current spec, so you can't get `[ "a", "b" ]`.  If you feel this is an important and common use case, please add an issue to the [OAI Spec](https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification) repository.

Comment: "example" is a  default parameter in swagger huh??.. If i pass "example":"a" am getting null value for it. please guide me..if i did any wrong. Expected result is "taskstatusList":["a"]  but am getting  "taskstatusList":[null]